# Muon is stuck on lubuntu cosmic. How do I get off this dead end?

Tags: apt, lubuntu

[Muon](https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1127868/) is using cosmic. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ does list cosmic. I do not see any reference to cosmic in the GUI but, I get an error saying it cannot find the file in the cosmic directory. Where can I see where Muon says it wants cosmic? How do I change it?

```
$ apt-cache policy muon
muon:  
  Installed: 4:5.8.0-1ubuntu4
  Candidate: 4:5.8.0-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
  *** 4:5.8.0-1ubuntu4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:        18.10
Codename:       cosmic
```

/etc/apt/sources.list lists cosmic but where is this specified/shown with Muon?

[image: /etc/apt/sources.list lists]

Comment: I don't see `cosmic` in http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/. Cosmic is end-of-life now. What does your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contain?

Comment: It's implied - `cosmic` is the release name, so where it says `main`, `universe`, etc., those are all for `cosmic`. And that is from the standard Software  Sources GUI, which is independent of muon.

Comment: @muru Where is that seen from within Muon?

Answer (score 0):

As @muru pointed out, [Ubuntu 18.10 EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/) was more than a year ago and its repositories were removed from main mirrors and moved to old-releases.ubuntu.com. Ubuntu 18.10 codename is "Cosmic Curtlefish", that's where the "cosmic" comes from. Muon is basically complaining about *cosmic* repositories not being available.

You need to replace `archive.ubuntu.com` and `us.archive.ubuntu.com` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` with `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`.

And you should also upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu soon.